# count inversions of 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, inversion

I want to find the number of inversions possible in a 2D array. I have written this program and need ways to speed it up:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Solution
{
static long merge(int[] array, int[] left, int[] right)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
    while (i < left.length || j < right.length)
    {
        if (i == left.length)
        {
            array[i+j] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
        else if (j == right.length)
        {
            array[i+j] = left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if (left[i] <= right[j])
        {
            array[i+j] = left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            array[i+j] = right[j];
            count += left.length-i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

static long invCount(int[] array)
{
    if (array.length < 2)
        return 0;

    int m = (array.length + 1) / 2;
    int left[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, m);
    int right[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, m, array.length);

    return invCount(left) + invCount(right) + merge(array, left, right);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    long inversions=0;
    int[][] arr2=new int[n][n];
    if(n<0)
    {
        System.out.println("0");
        return;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            arr2[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
            //arr2[i][j]=arr[i][j];
        }

    long inv=0;
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            while(counter<n)
            {
                for(int z=counter;z<n;z++)
                {
                    //System.out.println("comparing "+arr2[i][counter]+" with "+arr2[j][z]);
                    if(arr2[i][counter]>arr2[j][z])
                        inv++;
                }
                counter++;
                //System.out.println("end while---------\n");
            }
            //System.out.println("Row change#########\n");
            counter=0;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
      inv=inv+invCount(arr2[i]);
    System.out.println(inv);
}
}
```

Can this program be optimized? Or is this program wrong somewhere?
I got correct output for 2 test cases which are: 4 inversions for 2D array:

```
9 7
1 2
```

and 19 inversions for 2D array:

```
9 7 6
1 2 5
2 3 1
```

Thanks for help.:)

Comment: Without understanding the problem, but I think wrapping your code into FOUR LOOPS is the basic problem, because you get a complaxity of about n^4 in the outer code alone, plus the (necessary) complexity n! for the inversion. Try reducing the outer loops.

Comment: Yes, The problem is indeed the loops and thats why i request to suggest some better method as i am not able to find one.

Comment: By 'inversion in a 2D array', do you mean exchanging 2 values that are either in the same row or in the same column? If yes, I think the result for a 3x3 matrix should be 18, not 19.

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
                inversionCount=0;
                for(R=0;R<sizeOf2DArray;R++) {
                    for(C=0;C<sizeOf2DArray;C++) {
                        firstElem=inputArray[R][C];
                        for(int j=R;j<sizeOf2DArray;j++) {
                            for(int i=C;i<sizeOf2DArray;i++) {
                                secondElem=inputArray[j][i];
                                if(firstElem>secondElem) {
                                    inversionCount++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
                System.out.println(inversionCount);
```